# How to combine SQL scalars correctly?

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

Having a few queries that return only one row and one column, how would you combine them in a single result set?

Example:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [col1] 
FROM [table] 
WHERE con1 = true 
ORDER BY [col1] DESC

SELECT TOP 1 [col1] 
FROM [table] 
WHERE con2 = true 
ORDER BY [col1] DESC
```

I could do this:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    (SELECT TOP 1 [col1] FROM [table] 
     WHERE con1 = true 
     ORDER BY [col1] DESC) AS 'Res1', 
    (SELECT TOP 1 [col1] FROM [table] 
     WHERE con2 = true 
     ORDER BY [col1] DESC) AS 'Res2'
FROM [table]
```

However it is not necessary that the results are combined as columns, the results in rows would be also ok or even as concatenation if that makes any sense, but maybe columns is already the better way.

I use SQL Server

Comment: There's no need for that outer reference to the table. Why not just `SELECT {Sub Query}, {Sub Query};`?

Comment: I dont know if i try that Syntax it doesnt compile

Comment: That syntax is perfectively valid, so that suggests you're doing something wrong.

Comment: "TOP 1 ... desc" is logically the same as MAX - which IMO is far more intuitive and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION` operator if the output fields are same for both queries

```
Query 1
Union
Query 2
```

Comment: Union seems to mess up the order in the queries

Comment: Try once with `Union All`. It will preserve order and also won't remove duplicates

Comment: I get into trouble with the syntax, i cant put a order by in front of Union or union all. If i put the order only at the end it will still not apply the order to the data

Comment: Correct, you would have to use subqueries, and `UNION ALL` those, @aludebe , The answer doesn't make it clear that you need to keep the queries as sub queries.

Comment: Is  a subquery something special that I dont get?

Comment: What do you mean by "Special", @aludebe ?

Comment: I  mean is this (Select x from y) not a subquery in general if you combine it with other queries?

Comment: A subquery is still a subquery, even if there are other subqueries within the query, @aludebe . I don't really understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Larnu answer is correct if you want to preserve order

Comment: Considering the OP's query doesn't have an order, @Deadlock (it's a single row), what "order" are you referring to?

Comment: This is the order OP want to preserve while merging `ORDER BY [col1] DESC`

Comment: I assign a order myself with the order by clause, it will change the outcome of the element from Top 1

Comment: Generally speaking, UNION ALL should be the default unless you know you need and want duplicate removal. Here it is entirely possible for the max value of both columns to be the same - resulting in a single row using your logic. In addition, resultset produced by any query has no defined order if the query has no ORDER BY clause. So no - order is not preserved nor guaranteed in your query.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, there's no need for the `FROM` in the outer query; just have your 2 subqueries:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT TOP (1)
               col1
        FROM dbo.[table]
        WHERE con1 = 1 --Boolean data types don't exists in SQL Server; I assume this is a bit
        ORDER BY col1 DESC) AS Res1, --Don't use string literals for aliases 
       (SELECT TOP (1)
               col1
        FROM dbo.[table] 
        WHERE con2 = 1 --Boolean data types don't exists in SQL Server; I assume this is a bit
        ORDER BY col1 DESC) AS Res2; --Don't use string literals for aliases
```

Comment: I got it. Can I use [Res1] for aliases instead? Because I think you have to avoid using an already used name in case there is such